# How to testing a service in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing

I want to test the data I receive from my service.
I read angular documentation and I followed observable example but I don't receive any data when I subscribed to the observable.
Console.log() isn't working inside the subscribe.

The service is working properly and get the right data in a real environment.

I tried to use async and doneFn but they didn't work both of them got time out.

Service File

```
export class BackService {

  URL = '********'; // I removed url for security.

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAllForms(): Observable<Array<object>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<object>>(`${this.URL}/allForms`);
  }

  getFormById(formId): Observable<Array<object>> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Array<object>>(`${this.URL}/form/${formId}`);
  }
}
```

Test Service File

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { BackService } from './back.service';


describe('BackService', () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let backService: BackService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
    providers: [BackService]
    });
    backService = TestBed.get(BackService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });
  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(backService).toBeTruthy();
  });
  describe('Methods', () => {
    describe('All Forms', () => {
      it('should use GET method', () => {
        backService.getAllForms().subscribe();
        const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${backService.URL}/allForms`);
        expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
      });
      it('should use the right url', () => {
        backService.getAllForms().subscribe();
        const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${backService.URL}/allForms`);
        expect(req.request.url).toBe(`${backService.URL}/allForms`);
      });
      it('should return the right data', () => {
        const mockData = [{'_id': 435345345, '_type': 'window'}]
        backService.getAllForms().subscribe(data => {
          expect(data).toEqual(mockData);
        });
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First 2 tests look ok, for third test to receive data that you can test on, you have to trigger that "httpMock" by calling its flush() method with necessary object you want your httpClient to return.

This should work for third test:

```
it('should return the right data', () => {
    const mockData = [{'_id': 435345345, '_type': 'window'}]
    backService.getAllForms().subscribe(data => {
      expect(data).toEqual(mockData);
    });
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(`${backService.URL}/allForms`);
    req.flush(mockData);
});
```

Comment: Also I suggest to use one test for one endpoint call - one test can include "expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');" method assertion along with data assertion in third test, that's why first test is not needed. Second test is also not needed as in my example url is already tested during data mocking

Comment: It fails 

 BackService › Methods › All Forms › should return the right data

    Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: *****, found none.

Comment: did you try declaring req variable at the bottom of the test? I updated code snippet at the last minute as I got the same error

Comment: Yeah know it's working fine. Thank you so much for your help Andrius

Answer (score 0):

we do pact tests because you have to mock a lot which didn't feel real for us.

**Example**

```
 import {PactWeb} from '@pact-foundation/pact-web';

    describe('FooService', () => {
    let provider: PactWeb;

      beforeAll(async () => {
        await provider.addInteraction({
                    state: 'I have an foo',
                    uponReceiving: 'a request to create an bar',
                    withRequest: {
                      method: 'POST',
                      path: '/url/bars',
                      body: {
                        foo: '123456',
                        bar: 'abcd'
                      }
                    },
                    willRespondWith: {
                      status: 200,
                      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                      body: {
                        foo: '123456',
                        bar: 'abcd'
                      }
                    }
                  });
               });

            it('should create one bar and respond with that bar', async () => {
              const service: FooService = TestBed.get(FooService);
              (service as any).apiBasePath = provider.mockService.baseUrl + 'url';
              const result = await service.createBar({
                        foo: '123456',
                        bar: 'abcd'
              }).toPromise();

              expect(result.id).toEqual('some-random-uuid');

            });

    afterAll(function (done) {
      provider.finalize()
        .then(function () {
          done();
        }, function (err) {
          done.fail(err);
        });
    });
        });
```

I assume, that you have a service called "createBar" that you want to test.

**State** 
Is just to know what you are doing, so it is the state of the provider. He has a foo. And uponReceiving of the request he should create a bar

**withRequest** 
Shows how the request should look like

**willRespondWith**
Shows the response.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with MockBackend instead?

```
import { TestBed, inject } from "@angular/core/testing";
import {
  HttpModule,
  Http,
  Response,
  ResponseOptions,
  XHRBackend
} from "@angular/http";
import { MockBackend } from "@angular/http/testing";
import { BackService } from "./back.service";

describe("BackService", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [BackService, { provide: XHRBackend, useClass: MockBackend }]
    });
  });
  describe("getAllForms()", () => {
    it("should return an Observable<Array<Form>>", inject(
      [BackService, XHRBackend],
      (backService, mockBackend) => {
        const mockResponse = {
          data: [
            { id: 0, form: "Form 0" },
            { id: 1, form: "Form 1" },
            { id: 2, form: "Form 2" },
            { id: 3, form: "Form 3" }
          ]
        };

        mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
          connection.mockRespond(
            new Response(
              new ResponseOptions({
                body: JSON.stringify(mockResponse)
              })
            )
          );
        });

        backService.getAllForms().subscribe(forms => {
          expect(forms.length).toBe(4);
          expect(forms[0].form).toEqual("Form 0");
          expect(forms[1].form).toEqual("Form 1");
          expect(forms[2].form).toEqual("Form 2");
          expect(forms[3].form).toEqual("Form 3");
        });
      }
    ));
  });
});
```